# Kaon Photoproduction Reaction for FeynArts

Tags: physics, packages, feyncalc, wolfram-physics

I'm trying insert this kaon photoproduction into FeynArts (photon and proton to kaon+ and hyperon lambda):

[image]

any idea how to build this feynman diagram?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Have you checked the [documentation of FeynArts](https://feynarts.de/FA3Guide.pdf)? There are many examples included. If you still have troubles, please include the code that you have tried.